# url django formulario, no muestra diseño

Tags: css, bootstrap, django, django-urls

estoy enviando una url al correo del cliente 'reset/MQ/set-password/' , todo funciona bien , pero el diseño de css no me lo muestra.

el diseño los tengo en una carpeta por separado , y es solo en esa vista.

Comment: todos los archivos estaticos como CSS/JS..etc debe estar en una carpeta denominada 'static' tal como te lo comentan en la respuesta de abajo..

Comment: Puedes compartirnos tu settings por favor, especialmente la parte de STATIC_ROOT  O MEDIA_ROOT.

Comment: STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/") en la carpeta static tengo los archivos css y js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para cargar archivos estáticos(`css`, `js`, `imágenes`, `fonts`) en **`Django`** debes primero crear una carpeta dentro de tu proyecto llamada **`static`** y dentro de ella guardar los estilos, js, imágenes o fonts que necesites usar en un tu proyecto.

A continuación te ubicas en tu archivo `settings.py`, ubicado en la carpeta raíz de tu proyecto, y poner el siguiente código al final del archivo:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
```

Recuerda siempre en cada uno de los `templates` poner el **`tag`**

```
{%load staticfiles%}
```

Esto ayuda a que tu `template` busque los respectivos archivos estáticos dentro de esa carpeta

Además debes de agregar en tu `template` base dentro del **`head`** (si es que tienes, si no dentro del mismo `template` de la vista que requieres)

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'estilo.css' %}"  media="screen,projection"/>
```

Para así poder cargar tus estilos en el `template`.

Comment: listo, Solucionado, muchas gracias

Comment: Hola si resolvió tu problema, seleccionala como respuesta correcta